# Tool for merging WEB file with its change file

Tags: web

Is there any tool that can take a `sample.web` and `sample.ch` file and produce a `merged.web` file as output?

Comment: I'm familiar with WEB, but what exactly is `ch`, again?  (It may even be beneficial to produce something of an MWE -- maybe a minimal WEB file, a minimal change file, and what the result should be after `mysteryprog sample.web sample.ch -o merged.web` (say).)

Comment: *.ch means change file.

Comment: See the edit to my comment; I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the `mysteryprog`. I read that platform dependent changes to a *.web program should be made by adding a change file (*.ch). I am trying to find if there is a program that can produce the resulting merge.web file.

Comment: The whole point of a `.ch` file is to use it along with the `.web` with `tangle` to extract the program.

Comment: So, tagging of of Joseph's comment, merging the web and change files would be a violation of intent -- it was never meant to be that way.  It's like making new paragraphs in LaTeX by saying `\newline\newline`.  If you need platform-dependent documentation, I would believe you'd use `weave` similarly.

Comment: There seems to be a program called PATCHWEB or TIE to do this. ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/webmerge.tex

Answer (score 2):

The tool is `tangle` try:

```
   tangle inputfile changefile outputfile poolfile
```

If not available with standard distributions, try `ctangle`. Also instructive is to read [webman](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/web.zip). Good reference [here](http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=2529).

Comment: I thought `weave`  was for extracting the `.tex` part of a WEB file

Comment: @JosephWright You right, running low on memory. Both can be used though on changefiles, one for docs and another for PASCAL. By the time you compile TeX is a 21 step process:)